# How to compare 12-hour/24-hour formatted time strings in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, type-conversion, comparison-operators

How do I compare which time string is greater; be it in 24-hour or 12-hour format?

For example, `"9:42:54" vs "19:25:31"` or `"9:42:54 AM" vs "7:25:31 PM"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to compare strings in time format, you need to convert them to TimeSpan or DateTime objects, but the former seems to be more relevant:

```
TimeSpan time1 = TimeSpan.Parse("9:42:54");
TimeSpan time2 = TimeSpan.Parse("19:25:31");
```

or

```
TimeSpan time1 = DateTime.Parse("9:42:54").TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan time2 = DateTime.Parse("19:25:31").TimeOfDay;
```

However, using `TimeSpan.Parse` for 12-hour time string formats will throw a `System.FormatException`. Use `DateTime.Parse` instead and take only the time part of the created `DateTime` object:

```
TimeSpan time1 = DateTime.Parse("9:42:54 AM").TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan time2 = DateTime.Parse("7:42:54 PM").TimeOfDay;
```

As a benefit, converting to TimeSpan will also give you a chance to apply [TimeSpan operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332455%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like regular comparison, subtraction, addition, etc.:

```
if (time1 > time2)
{
    // time1 is greater
}
else if (time1 < time2)
{
    // time2 is greater
}
else
{
    // They are equal
}
```

You can also use [TimeSpan.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact.aspx) if you need to the specify the time format of your string explicitly.

Comment: Or convert them into a `LocalTime` value in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), which actually represents what we're trying to represent - a time of day.

Comment: Why the focus on TimeSpan? The OP clearly has points in time, conversion to a DateTime is enough.

Comment: @JonSkeet Noda Time seems to be an alternative for people who can use third-party APIs in their applications.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, pardon my curiosity, what does OP stand for? Since we are trying to compare times, I thought TimeSpan would be more relevant and appropriate.

Comment: @anario OP = Original Poster - i.e. you (in the context of your question, not as self-answerer). Out of interest, JonSkeet is one of the authors of the (IMO excellent) NodaTime library.

Comment: @anario: Yes, it is. Can you *not* use 3rd party libraries?

Comment: @JonSkeet, it depends on which project I am working on. At work, for example, we are not allowed to use third-party libraries out of security measures - we need to write our own. But other than that, in my personal projects I could surely use the library and I would be happy to. The other day I had this question, so I searched SO.com and couldn't find an answer (there were relevant answers though). Later when I found a solution, I considered to share with the community. Am I a bad person? :)